# Why is there an unnecessary or operation when inverting bytes?

Tags: c++, endianness, binary-operators

I am really confused by this, however trivial it may be.
Here's an example (which I tried on paper):

```
uint16_t val               = 32;                      //00000000 00100000
uint16_t swapped           = val >> 8;                //00100000 00000000
uint16_t swapped2          = val << 8;                //00100000 00000000
uint16_t swapped3          = (val >> 8) | (val << 8); //00100000 00000000
```

I may be missing something... But as far as I know, they all have the same value, I was wondering maybe the operation in "swapped3" was a safeguard/good practice when doing the same for unsigned 32 bit values, but it wouldn't make sense.

I've tried to search answers online, but all operations are either this or a play on it.

Enlighten me, if possible, binary operations make my head spin.

Comment: Try with `val > 256` and you will see the difference.
BTW, `swapped` (2nd line) seems wrong. It should read 0.

Comment: Hint: replace `32` with `0x1234` and you'll understand.

Comment: I think you are expecting shifting to rotate (i.e. bits "reappear" at the other end if you "shift them out"). It doesn't.

Comment: There is no rotation. So in case of `swapped` value is different https://godbolt.org/z/MhY71GMhj

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Perhaps write an explicit question, such as "What is this kind of swapping?" (of that is unclear), or "How does this code, swapping high an low byte of 16 bit integer, actually work?". Or, if your mistake and confusion comes from that invalid `swapped2` value in comment, and all is clear now, just say so in comments.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one language and delete the other tag.

Comment: The comment in the second line is wrong; the value of `val >> 8` is 0. That 1-bit just drops off the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many has already stated in the comments, the `>>` and `<<` operations are bitwise shifts, not bitwise rotations. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic.

In the most recent standard (C++20) they've added the rotations as well: see [rotr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/rotr) and [rotl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/rotl).